# Faceted Search Implementation using Hibernate Search + Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-search, faceted-search

I am looking for suggestions and working sample for implementing Faceted Search using Spring MVC and Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you looking for? The Hibernate Search documentation contains examples for the faceting API and there also some tests in the Hibernate Search source code which show how to use the API. If faceting is enabled during a search you can get a list of facets via:

```
List<Facet> facets = facetManager.getFacets( "myFacet" );
```

Stick this list into a scope which is available during the rendering phase and you should be able to iterate over the facets and build the page to your liking.